# Windows8 Push Notifications in Metro Application using HTML5

Tags: html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs, push-notification

I have a metro application in which am trying to display notifications whenever my service get updated.I tried to read Metro App push notification concepts overview from microsoft website and I observed Push Notifications sample but I did not get proper idea to implement push-notifications in Metro-apps?

Can anyone give me a sample example to implement push notifications in metro apps using HTML5 & JavaScript,really it will helpful to me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For *push* notifications, you need a server side component to perform the actual push of the notification. This is performed by your server sending a request to a specific URL -- that URL is obtained from your application which registers with your service. Clearly doing this in a pre-canned way is marginally non-trivial, although the process itself is not.

Details on how to obtain the URL, and how to send a notification to it:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465412.aspx (Getting the URL)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465450.aspx (Sending a notification to the URI)

If, however, you just want to update the tile for your application when it does something when the user is using it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465439.aspx is a good starting point.

The above links have snippets. There is a fully worked through sample for tiles/notifications on MSDN also:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Push-and-periodic-de225603 (Push)
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148 (Local)

Comment: thank you @Dominic,already I read those articles but am not able to implement server-side and client-side code,Can you give me a small sample example if you have,Really helpful to me. Thank you.

Comment: The code links has the samples your require. What specifically isn't working? Are you not getting the push notification? Or are you getting error codes? It's my understanding that getting all the certain etc on the server side can be a pain.

Comment: Actually am not able to start my server-side implementation as well as client-side also?Can you give advice how to start with simple example?

Answer (score 2):

I'm also working on the same. Here I'm sharing few links below which might be useful to you.

Prior to this, once read the [Guidelines and Checklist for implementing push notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761462.aspx).

Go through this link for [Implementing Windows 8 Push Notifications](http://www.jayway.com/2011/10/12/implementing-windows-8-push-notifications-an-example/).

Hope it Helps.