# How to Implement Push Notifications on Metro Apps

Tags: html, push-notification, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

Regarding push notifications. How to implement push notifications in Win8 Metro application. Here am using HTML5 and JavaScript to implement push notifications. I have tried by studying msdn concepts, but not get a clear idea to implement client-side and server-side code.

Can anyone provide me a sample example?

Help me guys. Thank you.

Comment: This looks to be very similar / dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827357/windows8-push-notifications-in-metro-application-using-html5/

Answer (score 1):

Here are some samples that may help you:

- [Push and periodic notifications client-side sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Push-and-periodic-de225603)
- [Raw notifications sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Raw-notifications-sample-3bc28c5d)
- [Toast notifications sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Toast-notifications-sample-52eeba29)

Also, check out the Quickstarts on the [Sending push notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465460.aspx) page; they walk through the process step-by-step.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you @Jennifer , I have tried by reading those articles but not got a clear idea on push notifications , Can u provide me a simple example if u have , It will really helpful to me. Thank you

Comment: There is a code walkthrough at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465412.aspx.  That code will get you started with creating a notification channel.  I don't know your specific scenario, but if you look at the topics in the left sidebar on that page, there are code walkthroughs of many other pieces of it (like updating a badge or sending a tile/toast notification).